# Transfer text to top line in txt - python

Tags: python, line, edit

I want to edit the file and the new text I send will be on the first line, not the bottom one.
I use this:

```
with open("OUTPUT.txt", "a") as myfile:
    myfile.write("row #2 text")
    myfile.write("\nrow #1 text")
```

But it will just add the text to a new line.

Thanks

SOLVED!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

with file('filename', 'r') as original: data = original.read()
with file('filename', 'w') as modified: modified.write("new first line\n" + data)